# How do I parse a html page using nodejs to find a qr code?

Tags: html, node.js, parsing

I want to parse a web page, searching for QRcodes in the page. When I find them, I am going to read them using the QRcode npm module.
The hard part is, I don't know how to parse the html page in a way I can detect the only the image tags that contains a QRcode inside it.

I tried finding some kind of pattern in the images that contain a Qr code, but it usually starts with "?qr" but I think the ending is different everytimwe.

I'm using the module require-promise to get the raw html, and then I parse through it

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States';

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    //success!
    console.log(html);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
  });
```

I want to be able to download the image of the QRcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the html returned into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const parser = require('node-html-parser');
const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States';

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    const data = parser.parse(html);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
  });
```

Then you can access things off the data object to find the QR code